# How to programmatically toggle webform required field

Tags: 7, webforms

Using webform4, how to programmatically toggle the required option based on another condition?
I have done `jQuery('#edit-submitted-fld4-rgistered-with').removeClass('required');` but it seems the validation is handled on the server side.

Comment: If field configured as required in drupal then you cannot move to form submission, Server side form validation will handle this, even if you try removing required attribute from front end also, it will not effect.

Comment: You may try with **Webform Conditional** module

Comment: According to this page https://www.drupal.org/node/1526208 Webform Conditional is not compatible with webform4.

Comment: I have a possible solution: Disabled required field on server, added jquery condition for HTML5 validation `$('#fld').prop('required',false);`

Comment: Then make your field non-manditory & from front end add required attribute or class to that field then toggle it by on your conditions :)